# How can I make the cursor stay hidden below an absolute div in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Check out [this page](http://jsbin.com/afagic) in IE 8.

Focus on the input box. The blinking cursor appears on top of the blue div. In Chrome and Firefox this does not happen.

Is this a browser bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: In IE they use a window-native textedit component. These components are put on top of everything, and are handled by the OS. Same with radio buttons, checkboxes and unstyles buttons. You can see this in action when looking at buttons under XP classic theme versus XP theme; in the former you get a gray button, in the latter a nice XP style button. This is not really a bug, and something you have to live with.

Comment: @Gerben - so, your answer simply "I cannot", right? You can put that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: There might be a work around. I'm not sure. It's just that it isn't a bug per see.

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed a problem with IE.

Maybe you can try to use a span element or something as an input field. Then, you can set an event handler to listen to a key pressed.

For example, the following JavaScript snippet allows to insert a character into the innerHTML of an element:

```
function addChar(element, event) {
    if (!event) event = window.event;
    element.innerHTML += String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
}
```

...and the HTML snippet:

```
<span onkeypress="addChar(this, event);"></span>
```

Note that you still need a workaround to prevent the browser to navigate to the previously visited webpage when pressing BACKSPACE.

That can be done with `event.preventDefault()` for example. Or you can use

```
<body onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==8||event.keyCode==13)return false;">
```

or something.

On http://www.mcemperor.nl/test/hidecaret/, you can see an example.